# What is drupal.aspcode.net?

Tags: discussion

drupal.aspcode.net seems to be copying the contents of this site and Google shows their site along with search results from this site, which is annoying. Anyone know what's going on there?

Comment: I'm on tablet, or I would look it up.  There is a post on Meta Stack Exchange about the procedure for reporting scraper sites like this.

Comment: Found it, thanks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Answer (score 4):

It's just a site that scraps content from a Stack Exchange site. They are doing correctly, since:

- They report from where they took the content (It's the "Data coming from Stack Exchange Network" phrase on the footer.)
- There are links to the user profiles (It's for the user who asked the question, since there are just questions.)
- There is a link to the question on Stack Exchange, where the answers are visible

I don't understand the reason to show a list of question without answers, but if the sites help finding answers here, I don't think it is making any damage.